# Date parse in php not returning as expected

Tags: php, date

So, I am trying to parse a string,eg. 1-5-2014, to a DATE type like so:

```
$todayArray = date_parse_from_format("n-j-Y", $row["whenn"]);
$news_date = strtotime($todayArray['year'].'-'.$todayArray['month'].'-'.$todayArray['day']);
```

But it returns as 1399909000. It seems like it is the array that is causing the problem but with my limited knowledge of php I have no idea as to what is wrong.

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

Comment: What value are you expecting?

Comment: 2014-02-01 at least for the example I gave

Comment: Please read the [documentation for `strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) it returns the number of seconds since the unix epoch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `$todayArray` should be something like this:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2014
    [month] => 1
    [day] => 5
    [hour] => 
    [minute] => 
    [second] => 
    [fraction] => 
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_localtime] => 
)
```

Now the string

```
$todayArray['year'].'-'.$todayArray['month'].'-'.$todayArray['day']
```

i.e. `"2014-1-5"` is a valid argument for [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime). But the function will return `1393355280`, the [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) corresponding to the given date, and that is not what you’re trying to obtain. In fact, the above string is already quite similar to your desired output. The only problem is that the values of `$todayArray['month']` and `$todayArray['day']` need to be zero-padded on the left side. This can be easily achieved with [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
$news_date = $todayArray['year'].'-'.sprintf("%02d", $todayArray['month']).'-'.sprintf("%02d", $todayArray['day']);
```

Now the value of `$news_date` is `"2014-01-05"`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `strtotime()` as it just converts your date into a Unix Timestamp. Using `DateTime()` also makes this simpler than using `date_parse_from_format()`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("n-j-Y", $row["whenn"]);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```